# Cleaner way to repeat imageview, textview, and checkbox list in Kotlin android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, class, kotlin, oop

I'm basically creating a todolist app in android studio with kotlin that has this structure on repeat throughout the entire page. The button is for adding more items to your to do list. So to make things cleaner I'd like to make a simple class object everytime that button is pressed and add it to the layout. I'm fairly new to Kotlin and android and have no idea the best way to do this and don't want to just hardcode a new layout everytime a button is pressed. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
<LinearLayout>
     <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:id="@+id/weekly_button_1"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:background="@drawable/plus_sign" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/monthly"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:text="@string/monthly"
        android:textSize="40dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

      <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkbox_1"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/daily_item_1"
            android:textSize="16sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: use adapter and recycle view

Answer (score 0):

you can checkout the below codelabs example.

https://developer.android.com/codelabs/kotlin-android-training-diffutil-databinding#4